# Oracle EBS r12 - modelling ERD with no FK' constraints in the database....transformation script?

Tags: foreign-keys, oracle11g, constraints, erd

As per subject I am looking for, for a way to model Oracle EBSr12 db in standard modelling tool (toad / sql dev data modeller etc).

Problem is that Oracle doesn't use FKs in that database - therefore standard ERD modelling procedures / tools simply don't work.

I know that all FK relationships are contained in FND_foreign_Keys tables - is there a way of either extracting them and apply to imported schemas in data modeller (or other tools) or simply create them in the database directly using extracted data from those tables?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm currently running in circles around that issue.

Thing to note is that "discover relationship" option from SQLdev / data modeler is not accurate as its only based on naming schemas - it doesn't produce any meaningful results.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write SQL against FND_FOREIGN_KEYS that builds properly formatted SQL that would create foreign keys.  At that point you could:

- instantiate those foreign keys and reverse engineer the database, then drop the foreign keys
- import the SQL to the model (not all modeling tools may support this)

Assuming the layout of the FND_FOREIGN_KEYS table is:

```
APPLICATION_ID              NUMBER(15)   
TABLE_ID                    NUMBER(15)  
FOREIGN_KEY_ID              NUMBER(15)   
FOREIGN_KEY_NAME            VARCHAR2(30)
LAST_UPDATE_DATE            DATE   
LAST_UPDATED_BY             NUMBER(15)
CREATION_DATE               DATE
CREATED_BY                  NUMBER(15)
LAST_UPDATE_LOGIN           NUMBER(15)
PRIMARY_KEY_APPLICATION_ID  NUMBER(15)
PRIMARY_KEY_TABLE_ID        NUMBER(15)   
PRIMARY_KEY_ID              NUMBER(15)   
CASCADE_BEHAVIOR            VARCHAR2(1)
FOREIGN_KEY_RELATION        VARCHAR2(1)
DESCRIPTION                 VARCHAR2(240)
CONDITION                   VARCHAR2(2000)
ENABLED_FLAG                VARCHAR2(1)
```

Writing such SQL looks fairly straightforward.